# Play 2.2: [main] [EventStream(akka://application)] [akka.event-handlers] config is deprecated, use [akka.loggers]

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, playframework-2.2

Since upgrading to Play 2.2 I've seen this warning in my logs:

`[main] [EventStream(akka://application)] [akka.event-handlers] config is deprecated, use [akka.loggers]`

I haven't specified any specific Akka logging; and it isn't causing any trouble as of yet.

I've seen some other Play 2.2 users comment on having this warning; however no-one named a solution with their comments as of yet.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to disable this deprecation notice by configuring the `akka.loggers` value exclusively in your `conf/application.conf`, something like the following:

```
akka {
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    log-dead-letters = 1
    log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      debug.lifecycle = off
    }
}
```

The important line you need is `akka.loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]`.

Play includes logback as a dependency so you shouldn't require any additional JAR files with the above configuration.